# IBOutletCollection and tag attribute

Tags: ios, xcode

I have one doubt. please answer me these questions. 1.why we use IBOutletCollection instead of IBOutlet? 2. If we use four button using IBOutletCollection, how to find which button triggered? 3. what is tag attribute? and usage of tag attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the proper  IBOutletCollection button like this

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSMutableArray *buttonToSelected;
```

here you can see selected button

```
 -(IBAction)selectedButton:(id)sender
    {
      for (UIButton *btn in self.buttonToSelected)
      {
         if (sender == btn)
         {
            btn.isSelected == !btn.isSelected
         }
      }
    }
```

try like this

Comment: Thanks. :) what about tag attribute ? can i select button using tag attribute?

Comment: when btn is selected now you can get all the info of button

Comment: use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray

Comment: Your code can do a little better:    
    -(IBAction)selectedButton:(id)sender

        NSInteger indexObject = [newButtonsArray indexOfObject:sender];
        if(indexObject != NSNotFound)
        {
            [sender setSelected:!sender.selected];
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

> why we use IBOutletCollection instead of IBOutlet?

Because sometime you are not interested in individual items. IBOutletCollections are usually used to bulk change attributes. For example UILabels where you want to change the font. Or UIButtons where you want to change the borderWidth of the layer.

You use them when you care about the representation of a view and not its content.

> If we use four button using IBOutletCollection, how to find which button triggered?

You usually should not use IBOutletCollection for this. Create individual IBOutlets. You can do both, it's perfectly fine to have one UIButton in a IBOutletCollection and have an individual IBOutlet for it as well.

IBOutletCollections are in no way designed to replace IBOutlets.

> what is tag attribute? and usage of tag attribute?

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag). Tags are most useful when you create ad-hoc  views in code. If you have a UIViewController or a UIView subclass I would not use them.
Because `if (sender == self.addButton)` is much more clear than `if (sender.tag == 2)`

Answer (score 0):

First and second question answer visit below link

http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/

**Tag**

An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.

**Usage:**

The default value is 0. You can set the value of this tag and use that value to identify the view later.